# How to copy a object into formview and save to objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, objectdatasource

I have a wizard page, need copy a object from a gridview, then edit some property to save to an new object.

My formview like

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" EnableViewState="False" DataKeyNames="key" DefaultMode="ReadOnly">
   <ItemTemplate>
     ...
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}"
        InsertMethod="Insert" SelectMethod="GetById" TypeName="xxx.xxx"
        DataObjectTypeName="xxx.xxxx">
```

**I have to use DataObjectTypeName**

```
Protected Sub step3Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles step3Save.Click
     objectDatasource2.Insert()
End Sub
```

When call objectDatasource2.Insert(), throw exception said datasource do not have values.  Is there any solution to insert a Object as parameter of ObjectDatasource?

Answer (score 0):

I would set the CommandName of the button control to "Insert", rather than specifying objectDatasource2.Insert() in the event handler sub routine.  Have a look at this link here: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=9878983.